# I get the following errors logged when I try install my output media file which I built using Install4j version 10.0.1. Installation does not complete

Tags: javafx, install4j, java-17

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.install4j.api.styles.Style.setControlButtonVisible(com.install4j.api.context.ControlButtonType, boolean)" because "this.style" is null
at com.install4j.runtime.beans.styles.NestedStyleComponent.setControlButtonVisible(NestedStyleComponent.java:106)
at com.install4j.runtime.beans.styles.FormStyle.lambda$setControlButtonVisible$3(FormStyle.java:104)
at com.install4j.runtime.beans.styles.FormStyle.visitControlButtonContainers(FormStyle.java:178)
at com.install4j.runtime.beans.styles.FormStyle.setControlButtonVisible(FormStyle.java:104)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.setControlButtonVisible(ScreenEnvelope.java:220)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.activate(ScreenEnvelope.java:159)
at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardBase.setScreen(WizardBase.java:123)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.WizardScreenExecutor.execute(WizardScreenExecutor.java:272)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.lambda$execute$0(Controller.java:177)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com with your project file attached and let us know how you created or migrated this project.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix is to reset the styles under "Installer->Screens & Actions->Styles" to their default (the blue button with the reset arrow)

Comment: I downgraded install4j from version 10.0.1 to version 9.0 and it worked. Seems the issue is with the later version on install4j

Comment: Yes, but we don't know how this can happen, so it would be great if you share the steps to create this problem including the project file to support@ej-technologies.com